# Reducing smoking and mental health benefits

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, depression, drugs

Recently I noticed improved mental health (better mood, better cognition? more energy) after **reducing** smoking.Is it backed up by research?
I know stopping smoking is, but reducing?

http://www.pulsetoday.co.uk/clinical/clinical-specialties/mental-health/stopping-smoking-as-effective-as-antidepressants-at-improving-mood/20005864.article